# Meteor.js - bugs on Todo App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

It seems that there are bugs/ mistakes in Meteor.js [Todo App](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections):

```
3.2  Load tasks collection on the server server/main.js

import '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
import './imports/api/tasks.js';
```

?

Also:

```
$ meteor mongo
$ db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });
```

I run that two lines. Nothing is changed on my screen.

No database is created at all, so how can you add a document in tasks?

Any ideas?

Comment: I have followed the tutorial and it seems to be quite correct, what do you get when you type this: db.tasks.find()?

Comment: import '../imports/api/tasks.js'; is correct as server and imports are in the same folder level.

Comment: I do get list docs.`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5995a6d48b9d10c9be29fb72"), "text" : "Hello world!", "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-17T14:23:16.949Z") }` But the app is not picking up anything.

Comment: ` '../imports/api/tasks.js'; ` gives me error on my browser console : `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../imports/api/tasks.js'`

Comment: ok, it has added the document to the tasks collection.  Run this command: find ./imports/ -type f, and put the files it found: imports//api/tasks.js, imports//ui/body.html, imports//ui/body.js